# jQuery hover() and how to get it to work seamlessly

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, jquery-hover

I've got the following code to implement a carousel, when user performs hover randomly for a few seconds, it looks like jquery hover() puts them in a queue and execute all. How I want that carousel to work is only execute the latest hover.

```
$('#broker_carousel_controls li a').hover(function (e) {            
        e.preventDefault();
        var t = $(this);
        var speed = 'fast';
        $('#broker_carousel_controls li a.bcc_active').removeClass('bcc_active');
        var idx = $('#broker_carousel_controls li a').index(t);
        t.addClass('bcc_active');

        $('#broker_carousel li:visible').hide(speed, function () {

        });
        $('#broker_carousel li').eq(idx).show(speed, function () { 
            //busy = false;             
        });


    }, function () { });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.stop()` before your `hide` and `show` functions. `stop()` stops the current animation so the next can start immediately. I use it sometimes to prevent such event queueing.

```
$('#broker_carousel li:visible').stop().hide(speed, function () {
});
$('#broker_carousel li').eq(idx).stop().show(speed, function () { 
    //busy = false;             
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the hover event you can keep a variable of the last item needed to be shown.  Then check that variable in your callback function for show. This makes for a max of 2 show / hides if they are just wildly moving over things and doesn't have a stutter when you use `.stop()`  I wrote the following real fast, but you should get the idea.

```
$('#broker_carousel_controls li a').hover(CarouselHover
, function () { });

var lastQueue = null;
function CarouselHover(e)
{
        e.preventDefault();
        if (lastQueue == null)
        {
          lastQueue = this;
          StartHoverShow();
        }
        else
        {
          lastQueue = this;
        }
}

function StartHoverShow()
{
      if (lastQueue != null)
      {
        var t = $(lastQueue);
        lastQueue = null;
        var speed = 'fast';
        $('#broker_carousel_controls li a.bcc_active').removeClass('bcc_active');
        var idx = $('#broker_carousel_controls li a').index(t);
        t.addClass('bcc_active');

        $('#broker_carousel li:visible').hide(speed, function () {

        });
        $('#broker_carousel li').eq(idx).show(speed, function () { 
            //busy = false;  
           ShowCallback();
        });
      }
}

function ShowCallback()
{
  if (lastQueue != null)
  { 
    StartHoverShow();
  }
}
```